# After creating a product how can I publish it to the online store in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'm creating new product using the **productCreate** mutation. Now I want to publish it to my online store.

To do that I'm querying the list of publications using the **[publications](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/unstable/queries/publications)** query but the challenge I'm facing is to determine which publication id belongs to the online store? Previously they had a "name" property which is now deprecated.

Once I become certain that this id belongs to the online store then I can publish it using the **[publishablePublish](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-10/mutations/publishablePublish)** mutation.

Also how can I set the inventory quantity of a newly created product?

Thanks!